# Apply formula for rows with first occurence of text

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, counting

I want to achieve something like the image below:

[image]

How can I do it?

Comment: I do not use Google sheets but check if there's a possibility to use `COUNTIF` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(COUNTIFS(A:A, A:A, ROW(A:A), "<="&ROW(A:A))=1, 
 "first occurance", ))
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this normal Excel formula works just fine.

Assuming your data starts from cell `A1`, insert following formula

`=IF(COUNTIF($A$1:A1,A1)=1,"First Occurrence","")`

Then copy down as much as you need.